Do people in GT cars experience twice the amount of g-forces than astronauts on lift-off?
In the 2023 movie Gran Turismo, when the winners of the application competition are first in GT Academy, Jack Salter says,

When you’re in a race, the g-forces will be twice what an astronaut experiences upon lift-off.

Is this true?

Wikipedia states that the Saturn V generated 1.25 g at lift-off (which a GT car could easily double), but I can't find those figures in the listed citation so I'm hesitant to make that an answer.

@F1Krazy I found a reference that mentions g-forces for F1 drivers, not GT (~5).

Oxford Reference says "Early astronauts were subjected to launch and re-entry forces of up to 6 g or more; in the space shuttle, more than 3 g is experienced on lift-off.".

@RayButterworth for the latter, likely due to the SRBs - those are all thrust. Saturn V was all-liquid and that ends up with a lower acceleration. I’d be unsurprised by re-entry forces being higher though for capsules

The max G-force on a car is when cornering, not when accelerating.

@fyrepenguin the fuel source doesn't influence the acceleration, the thrust to weight ratio does. The Saturn V was a fantastic rocket, but its thrust to weight ratio was very low, leading to very slow acceleration and thus low g forces. The Shuttle (especially when lightly loaded) jumped off the pad, high acceleration and thus high g loads.

@jwenting sure, the TWR directly determines the acceleration, but the type of propellant tends to play a role in that. Just look at the comparative TWR of the Shuttle and boosters - the shuttle+tank is highly efficient but can’t get off the ground on its own (TWR under 1), while the solid boosters get about 2.5 TWR for a full-stack TWR of about 1.5. Solids are usually a trade off of high thrust for worse efficiency, hence the need for side boosters for the Shuttle. Look at most solid fueled rockets and you’ll generally see TWRs higher than liquid fueled rockets.

@fyrepenguin you're describing a symptom, not the disease, so to speak.

Formula 1 pilots experience up to 6 G at  braking or cornering, the  max G being 3 in case of acceleration, comparable to that of the space shuttle lift-off.

@WeatherVane https://www.reddit.com/r/physicsmemes/comments/nzeh4h/you_get_an_accelerator_and_you_get_an_accelerator/

Depends on the flight, and if its launch or re-entry. Space.SE has the numbers for crewed space flight.

Lift-off acceleration of an orbital rocket is quite modest - about 1.2g for the Saturn V and about 1.5g for the shuttle. As fuel burns off and the mass of the rocket decreases, acceleration increases to a maximum of 4g for Saturn V and 3g for shuttle.

Rockets don't actually accelerate that hard at liftoff.  The manned rocket I've found with the highest liftoff thrust-to-weight ratio, the Mercury-Atlas, only has a launch acceleration of 1.6 g; in second place is the Space Shuttle, at 1.4 g.
I don't know what the hardest-accelerating Gran Turismo racecar is, but Wikipedia says the Porsche 911 GT1 can go from 0 to 60 mph at an average acceleration of 0.8 g.
Comparing these is tricky.  A rocket with a thrust-to-weight ratio of 1 won't be going anywhere: the entire output of the engines is going into countering gravity, while the Porsche's output goes entirely into speed.  Measured in terms of speed gain, the Porsche has twice the effective acceleration of the Space Shuttle, but if you were to fire the Mercury-Atlas down a racetrack, it would accelerate twice as hard as the Porsche.
However, the peak g-forces of racing aren't from linear acceleration, but from cornering.  I can't find numbers for Gran Turismo racing (search results are getting swamped by the popular video-game series of that name), but for Formula 1, it appears to be around 6 times the force of gravity, and there's no reason to think that GT racing is any different.  That's far more than twice the acceleration of a manned rocket at liftoff regardless of how you compare things.

Those numbers are absolutely correct for liftoff, so I 100% think this answer is correct to the question as stated, though Schwern’s comment under the question linked to a Space.SE answer showing the full acceleration curves for launch, which actually peaked nearly at 8g on Mercury-Atlas missions. So the quoted source in the question may be deliberately cherry-picking numbers (liftoff-only) to make a point.

The claim is technically correct, therefore, which is the best kind of correct.
